# docker-compose poetry multicommand

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fastapi, poetry

Я пытаюсь собрать docker-compose, в сервисе app я пытаюсь выполнить миграции и запустить uvicorn, но у меня выполняеться только миграции и не поднимаеться uvicorn

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот так выглядит docker-compose

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    build: .
    restart: always
    command: > 
      poetry run alembic upgrade head && poetry run uvicorn src.main:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    healthcheck:
      test: [ 'CMD', 'redis-cli', '--raw', 'incr', 'ping' ]
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD', 'pg_isready', '-U', 'admin']
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '5050:80'
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy

#  celery:
#    container_name: celery
#    build: tasks/.
#    restart: always
#    env_file:
#      - .env
#    depends_on:
#      - app
```

Dockerfile от сервиса app

```
FROM python:3.11-alpine3.18

RUN pip install poetry
RUN apk update

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/

RUN poetry install
```